# using shell script to posting Json body to curl by loop

Tags: curl, for, json

I have many Json file which need to be post to curl. so how to write loop for the same? am trying this way

```
for FILES in $~/network_map_ingestion/networkmap/data/consolidation
ls NetworkMap-*.json;
do
echo $file
#curl -X POST --data @$file -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://10.00.00.0000000/ingestion/entities/wsr/scp/ekl
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over all the files. You don't need `ls`, just use shell globbing:

```bash
for file in ~/network_map_ingestion/networkmap/data/consolidation/NetworkMap-*.json
do
    printf 'Processing "%s"\n' "$file"
    curl -X POST --data @"$file" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        'http://10.00.00.0000000/ingestion/entities/wsr/scp/ekl'
done
```

With an up to date release of `curl`, this may be shortened to

```bash
for file in ~/network_map_ingestion/networkmap/data/consolidation/NetworkMap-*.json
do
    printf 'Processing "%s"\n' "$file"
    curl --json @"$file" 'http://10.00.00.0000000/ingestion/entities/wsr/scp/ekl'
done
```